# Kentico CMS: Page not found URL

Tags: content-management-system, http-status-code-404, kentico

**Kentico CMS**

I have created a custom 404 page to redirect to when someone hits a 404/page not found error.

And then in `Site Manager > Settings > Content` I have added the URL location for this custom page.

Now when I try to navigate to a page that doesnt exist in my site I still get the standard 404 Server Error page. Why is it not redirecting to my custom page?

**Site Structure:**
[image]

**Site Manager > Settings Page:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using extensionless urls (looks like it), have you changed the 404 settings within IIS? You need to map the 404 error to Kentico's handler, /cmspages/handler404.aspx.

[IIS 7 Instructions](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?custom_url_extensions_iis7.htm).
[IIS 6 Instructions](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/custom_url_extensions_iis6.htm?zoom_highlightsub=404)

Comment: thanks I'm getting my colleague to look into this solution. I have found this downloadable kit to use (http://devnet.kentico.com/Marketplace/Utilities/Page-Not-Found-Kit.aspx), basically I think it provides a web part to use on the 404 page. Do you have any knowledge of this? i.e. will it help me or is the answer you provided a better solution?

Comment: @DaveHaigh Hard to say really, but if the marketplace thing works, then go for that. You'll likely have to go through the IIS settings at some point I would think when setting things up.

Comment: going through some of the IIS settings fixed the problem. thank you.

Comment: @Doozer Blake, using the handler404.aspx method is obsolete according to the documentation: [link](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/custom_url_extensions_iis7.htm?zoom_highlightsub=404#)

Comment: @LordHits I'm reading that as in IIS7 in certain modes, it appears that it is. It's still necessary for IIS 6 though as far as I know.

Comment: @Doozer Blake you are correct. Here's the [link for IE6](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/custom_url_extensions_iis6.htm?zoom_highlightsub=404).